# Google cloud function error with wheels & pywin32

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to deploy a script on google cloud functions for the first time. I went through the documentation and figured out the basics. Then, I started trying to deploy my actual script. I'm facing an error with dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file. I'm at the stage where I don't know enough to be specific about my problem so I'll list down what I did.

After I run the gcloud command `gcloud functions deploy FILENAME --runtime python37` with my file name, I hit this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: 
{
  "error": {
    "canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "errorMessage": "`pip_download_ wheels` had stderr output:\nERROR: Could not find 
                      a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32)) 
                      (from versions: n one)\nERROR:\r\nNo matching distribution found for pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
                      \n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1",
    "errorTyp e": "InternalError",
    "errorId": "8C994D6A"
  }
}
```

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
attrs==19.3.0
autobahn==20.4.3
Automat==20.2.0
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.9.2
enum34==1.1.10
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-auth==1.14.1
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.9
incremental==17.5.0
kiteconnect==3.8.2
numpy==1.18.3
pandas==1.0.3
protobuf==3.11.3
pyarrow==0.17.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
pywin32==227
requests==2.23.0
rsa==4.0
service-identity==18.1.0
six==1.14.0
tqdm==4.45.0
Twisted==20.3.0
txaio==20.4.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wincertstore==0.2
zope.interface==5.1.0
```

Can you help me figure out how to get past this error?

---

Edit: Based on the suggestion to only keep required dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file, I tried that and I'm getting a slightly different error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed:
{
  "error": {
    "canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "errorMessage": "`pip_download_\r\nwheels` had stderr output:
                      \n  WARNING: Legacy build of wheel for 'kiteconnect' created no files.
                      \n  Command arguments: /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'imp\r\nort sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '\"'\"'/tmp/pip-wheel-fdr9r30n/kiteconnect/setup.py'\"'\"'; __file__='\"'\"'/tmp/pip-wheel-fdr9r30n/kiteconnect/s\r\netup.py'\"'\"';f=getattr(tokenize, '\"'\"'open'\"'\"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\"'\"'\\r\\n'\"'\"', '\"'\"'\\n'\"'\"');f.close();exec(compile(c\r\node, __file__, '\"'\"'exec'\"'\"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-zkanpa3p\n  Command output: [use --verbose to show]\nERROR: Failed to build one or more whe\r\nels\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1",
    "errorType": "InternalError",
    "errorId": "7EF920E4"
  }
}
```

The new `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-auth==1.14.1
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
kiteconnect==3.8.2
numpy==1.18.3
pandas==1.0.3
pyarrow==0.17.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
tqdm==4.45.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pywin32` package [only provides distributions for the Windows platform](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files), so you won't be able to install it in the Google Cloud Functions runtime.

Do you really need it? Your `requirements.txt` file looks like the output of `pip freeze`. You probably don't need all those dependencies. It should only include the dependencies you need to `import` in your function.

Comment: That makes sense! I tried to implement this by removing all the extra files and I'm getting a slightly different error now. It seems to something around pip wheels. I added the new error & requirements.txt  as an edit to my question. Any suggestions on what I can try next? Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: @Abhay Looks like that's an issue with the `kiteconnect` project: https://github.com/zerodhatech/pykiteconnect/issues/55